# having problem with comparing lists Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I started on this brute force password cracker because I wanted to see if I could do it. That would go through every possibilities.
It works fine but I wanted to add a way so it wouldn't repeat passwords.
the passwords are stored in a list and I'm trying to compare the new password to the previous passwords. I found some code that does this and decided to use it but it doesn't work for some reason.

here's the code:

```
def common_ele(list1, list2):
        a_set = set(tried)
        b_set = set(password)
        if len(a_set.intersection(b_set)) > 0:
            tested = True
            return True
        else:
            tested = False
        return False
```

here's my full code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import random
from collections.abc import Mapping, Sequence

keyboard = Controller ()
zer = ("0")
one = ("1")
two = ("2")
thr = ("3")
fou = ("4")
fiv = ("5")
six = ("6")
sev = ("7")
eig = ("8")
nin = ("9")

a = "a"
b = "b"
c = "c"
d = "d"
e = "e"
f = "f"
g = "g"
h = "h"
i = "i"
j = "j"
k = "k"
l = "l"
m = "m"
n = "n"
o = "o"
p = "p"
q = "q"
r = "r"
s = "s"
t = "t"
u = "u"
v = "v"
w = "w"
x = "x"
y = "y"
z = "z"

A = "A"
B = "B"
C = "C"
D = "D"
E = "E"
F = "F"
G = "G"
H = "H"
I = "I"
J = "J"
K = "K"
L = "L"
M = "M"
N = "N"
O = "O"
P = "P"
Q = "Q"
R = "R"
S = "S"
T = "T"
U = "U"
V = "V"
W = "W"
X = "X"
Y = "Y"
Z = "Z"

key = [zer,one,two,thr,fou,fiv,six,sev,eig,nin,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z]
increase = 0
loop = True
tested = False
test = True
tried = []
guess = ("")


time.sleep (2)

while (loop == True):

    test = True
    """length = random.randint(8,20)
    guess = random.choices(key,k=length)"""
    guess = ("hiiiiii")
    guess = "".join(guess)
    password = list(guess)

    #something wrong with this-----------------
    def common_ele(list1, list2):
        a_set = set(tried)
        b_set = set(password)
        if len(a_set.intersection(b_set)) > 0:
            tested = True
            return True
        else:
            tested = False
        return False
    #------------------------------------------

    while (test == True):
        
        if tested == True:
            length = random.randint(51,70)
            guess = random.choices(key,k=length)
            guess = "".join(guess)
            password = list(guess)
            print ("TRIED ALREADY")
        else:
            test = False
            print ("TESTED")
            tried.append(password)
            print (tried)

    for i in range(len(guess)):
        press = password[increase]

        time.sleep (0.1)
        
        keyboard.press(press)
        keyboard.release(press)
        
        increase = increase + (1)
    
    """for i in range(len(guess)):
        keyboard.press(press)
        keyboard.release(press)"""
    
    increase = (0)
    
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    
    with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl):
        keyboard.press("a")
        keyboard.release("a")
    
    print(password)
```

Comment: As it stands, this question doesn't have enough information for us to answer it. The intersection of two sets is another set containing the elements that are exactly the same in the two original sets. For instance, we don't know what `tried` nor `password` contains. Judging by the fact that `password` is singular, make sure you are passing in a list to the set constructor and not a string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So, `password` *is* a list, but not the one you expect. Because `guess` is a string, when you say `list(guess)`, it becomes a list containing each individual character as elements. For example:

```
guess = "password123"
password = list(guess)
```

`password` now stores:

```
['p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '1', '2', '3']
```

So, you then have your two sets (assume we've tried the passwords `"hello"` and `"stackoverflow"`):

```
set_a = ("hello", "stackoverflow")
set_b = ('p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '1', '2', '3')
```

See the problem? For this specific problem, you don't need a set intersection. You can actually just get away with using the `in` operator to check if `guess` is in `tried`:

```
if guess in tried:
  print("TRIED ALREADY")
```